# What does the is_final parameter in xml_parse() do?

Tags: php

I'm working on creating a class for xml parsing, and need to use this method from PHP called [`xml_parse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php).

It has 3 parameters like so:

`int xml_parse ( resource $parser , string $data [, bool $is_final = false ] )`

According to the PHP manual `is_final` it means whether its the last piece of data sent in this parse, but what does this mean? does this something have to do with `resource $parser`? as far as I'm aware this function does not allow an input stream of data, thus my confusion.

Someone please explain what it does

Comment: `A document may be parsed piece-wise by calling xml_parse() several times with new data, as long as the is_final parameter is set and TRUE when the last data is parsed.`

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate with an example? I'm still not quite sure how that would work.

Comment: Look example here http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php with reading file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_final` means that if you are parsing the last line of your `$data` you must set this parameter to true.

in addition there is a note in the Doc :

```
Entity errors are reported at the end of the parse. And will only show if the "end" parameter is TRUE
```

See the sample below from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_parse.asp)

```
<?php
$parser=xml_parser_create();

function char($parser,$data)
  {
  echo $data;
  }

xml_set_character_data_handler($parser,"char");
$fp=fopen("test.xml","r");

while ($data=fread($fp,4096))
  {
  xml_parse($parser,$data,feof($fp)) or 
  die (sprintf("XML Error: %s at line %d", 
  xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)),
  xml_get_current_line_number($parser)));
  }

xml_parser_free($parser);
?>
```

Comment: ah so you can input a stream of data (sorta), that clarifies a lot! thanks!